# ExpandableList array resource implementation questions

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I am not exactly clear on how to implement ExpandableList as array resource instead of hard-coded array (by replacing an existing hard-coded array with XML layout).  Here is my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">adaptor_ExpandableList1</string>

    <string name="expandable_list_sample_action">Sample action</string>
    <string-array name="Groups">
        <item>People Names</item>
        <item>Dog Names</item>
        <item>Cat Names</item>
        <item>Fish Names</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="People Names">
        <item>Arnold</item>
        <item>Barry</item>
        <item>Chuck</item>
        <item>David</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Dog Names">
        <item>Ace</item>
        <item>Bandit</item>
        <item>Cha-Cha</item>
        <item>Deuce</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Cat Names">
        <item>Fluffy</item>
        <item>Snuggles</item>      
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Fish Names">
        <item>Goldy</item>
        <item>Bubbles</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Here is what I changed in the Java file:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
    private String[] groups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Groups);
    private String[][] children = {getResources().getStringArray(R.array.People Names),
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Dog Names),
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cat Names),
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Fish Names)
    };
```

Of course R.array.xxx Names does not work.  So how can I correct the problem when there are statements in R.java such as this:   public static final int Cat Names=0x7f040003;.
There must be a rule for this but I don't know it yet.

Browsing through numerous examples, I think I also need to have group and child layout files and perhaps a main layout file (I think I know how to implement them if I need to).  Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have space in the name of string array

remove space from "people names" and other string array names.